# Combining jQuery selectors (select and id)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

[See this fiddle for code](http://jsfiddle.net/jaPTd/)

I have two `select` controls on a page, I want to select one of them using a combination of the id and the control type.

If I use the ID and control type, jquery returns a length of `0`.

```
 $('#bothCount').text($('#Title select').length);
```

NB: On some other page, I have an input with id `Title`, thats why I want to filter down to select controls only.

Comment: Do you mean `$('select#Title').length`? Does `$('#Title select').length` make sense? You are trying to find a select element which is within an element with ID of `Title`.

Comment: Id's must be unique. If you aren't using unique id's, you may get unexpected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector

```
#Title select
```

...is a [*descendant selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). It looks for any `select` that's a descendant of the element with the `id` `Title`.

If you really want to combine tag and `id`, you do it like this:

```
select#Title
```

E.g.:

```
$('#bothCount').text($('select#Title').length);
```

Note that there's usually little point in doing that, though, because `id` values have to be unique on a page. The only use case I know of for it is if you don't know what tag the element is going to have and you only want to act on it *if* it has a particular tag type, which is definitely an edge case.

Answer (score 2):

Change your JQuery to this:

```
$('#idCount').text($('#Title').length);

$('#bothCount').text($('select#Title').length);

$('#tagCount').text($('select').length);
```

Notice it is now `select#Title` as before you were trying to use a descendant selector.

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaPTd/1/).